# Notepad++ highlight text between keywords

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file that has data as follows:

```
Top
    Datum1
    Datum2
Bottom
    Datum 1
    Datum 2
Top
    Datum 1
    Datum 2
...
```

and I would like to select all of the data between the keywords "Top" and "Bottom". I have looked for the correct regex to accomplish this in Notepad++ but I haven't found the right information for my purpose. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You can't just select like that using Find, if it finds your string the entire found string will be highlighted/selected.  What is it you want to do with the lines you want to select?  Replace them with something, remove them, or ???

Comment: You want to highlight (mark) only the data between Top and Bottom
 but not Bottom and Top?

Comment: That's precisely it Yisroel Tech.

Comment: @Techie007 I would like to copy the highlighted text to the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a regex that will select all the text that is between each instance of Top and Bottom:

```
(?<=Top)([\s\S]*?)(?=Bottom)
```

to mark all in Notepad++ you just need to place this expression in the Mark find-box. See screenshot below.

Here you can see the expression and on the right side it explains what each character of the expression does: https://regex101.com/r/S5YGxj/1

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Yisroel Tech. This regex works perfectly to mark all of the desired text, but I am having trouble selecting all the marked text. I've followed the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298962/how-to-copy-marked-text-in-notepad) but the top two responses don't work because this regex only sets one bookmark for each set of data. Do you know how to select marked text?

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. (If it is then it's extremely complicated.) I'd suggest you using "Sublime" which does it with ease https://www.sublimetext.com/3